# Creating and submitting collections clientside, and then posting to server without AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

My Customer model has many Orders. I am collecting the data for multiple Orders clientside using jQuery.

What data structure is best for storing the Order collection clientside whilst I am building it?

How can I then submit this collection back to the server WITHOUT using ajax? Just when the user has finished building the Order collection and submits the form normally back to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's well presented here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

See episode 2 if needed:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2